# Are there any non-green, non-artifact mana ramp cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-manabase

I have looked and can't seem to find any.

I have seen many green cards and some artifacts that do this, but nothing in Red, Blue, Black or White.

Are there any?

**Note:** By "Mana Ramp" I mean a card that generates mana, or one that lets you play more than one land per turn.  The end result, for example, would be on turn 4, playing a white only deck, I could tap more than 4 mana.  (Normally you only get one land per turn so a max of 4 mana on turn 4.)

Comment: Just a quick one, because I love it; http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366452 Crypt Ghast has the ability: Whenever you tap a Swamp for mana, add 1 black mana to your mana pool (in addition to the mana the land produces). Effectively doubles your mana each turn in a monoblack deck :)

Comment: Not sure if it has been mentioned an any other comment, but for White and Blue it might be better to look to reducing the cost of spells rather than ramping, as there are a lot of cards that do that (as well as increasing the cost of your opponents spells).

Answer (score 21):

**There are, but they are purposefully few and far between.**

Mana acceleration is considered to be in green's part of the "color pie," with the exception of the occasional black card, and a little bit of a fast-mana theme in red (formerly black). Blue and white occasionally get ways to cheat on mana a bit, but only when they're tied into some other element of those colors.

[This answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/5034/1910) has discussion tailored to Commander, which also applies pretty well to other casual and multiplayer decks.

In competitive terms, the most relevant cards are:

- [Dark Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDark%20Ritual%5d) is *the* classic mana acceleration card, in black. It's still an influential card in Legacy.
- [High Tide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHigh%20Tide%5d) features in Legacy blue decks. The trick with this is to take one "big turn" where you develop tons of mana by playing cards that untap your lands, like [Time Spiral](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTime%20Spiral%5d) and [Candelabra of Tawnos](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCandelabra%20of%20Tawnos%5d).
- In Modern, [Desperate Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDesperate%20Ritual%5d), [Pyretic Ritual](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPyretic%20Ritual%5d), [Seething Song](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSeething%20Song%5d) (this one's banned at the moment) — along with [Manamorphose](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bManamorphose%5d), which actually gives you extra mana if you have a cost-reducer or copy-card in play — are commonly played in storm decks.
- In formats with fetchlands, [Deathrite Shaman](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeathrite%20Shaman%5d) is a mana dork that doesn't actually require a green deck to work very effectively.

Note that there are a lot of colorless cards that are used to cast normal colored cards (like [Ancient Tomb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAncient%20Tomb%5d)).

Also note that oftentimes it's more effective to "cheat" on costs (using reanimation or hand-to-play cards like [Show and Tell](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShow%20and%20Tell%5d)) than to accelerate your mana.

Comment: While Manamorphose can be played with only red mana because of the hybrid symbol, it is still a green card. The same is true of Deathrite Shaman being green and black.

Comment: @Andrew Only Commander players care about color identity in that way.

Comment: true, without color restrictions people don't tend to care about hybrid off colors - but in those cases people tend to be good with rocks - The question didn't mention any formats, it could be for say a Breya EDH deck (which would actually like rocks) or be purely academic, looking for cards that are specifically not green, like the question said.

Answer (score 7):

Mana ramp is definitely a very green thing; it's a natural effect for the color of life and growth (among other things). This is a great example of the color pie at work: there are just some things that not all the colors can do. But there are some cards outside green (and artifacts) that help produce mana.

In other colors, mana producing abilities are often more conditional - maybe it's a one-time effect, or maybe you have to pay something else to get it.

Here's [a Gatherer search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20!%5BG%5D%20!%5BC%5D&text=%20%5B%22to%20your%20mana%20pool%22%5D%20%5Badd%5D) that'll find (hopefully) all the directly mana-producing options (along with some things that don't actually ramp, like ones that just turn one color into another). The [same search restricted to Standard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20!%5BG%5D%20!%5BC%5D&text=%20%5B%22to%20your%20mana%20pool%22%5D%20%5Badd%5D&format=%7C%5B%22Standard%22%5D) only finds six cards, only three of which are repeatable: [Crypt Ghast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crypt%20Ghast), [Deranged Assistant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deranged%20Assistant), and [Liliana of the Dark Realms](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liliana%20of%20the%20Dark%20Realms). (Liliana isn't exactly speedy ramp, of course.) You could restrict to permanents if you don't want one-offs.

It's hard to search directly, but there are also non-green nonartifact things which help put lands onto the battlefield. Here's [a deliberately inclusive search](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20!%5BG%5D%20!%5BC%5D&text=%20%5Bland%5D%20%5B%22onto%20the%20battlefield%22%5D); most of those are false positives, but there are a few cards in there that put lands onto the battlefield for you: [Braids, Conjurer Adept](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Braids%2C%20Conjurer%20Adept), [Dreamscape Artist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dreamscape%20Artist), [Firebrand Ranger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Firebrand%20Ranger), [Knight of the White Orchid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Knight%20of%20the%20White%20Orchid), and so on. Again, they're more conditional - and this time, none of them are in standard. (And some of them are from Planar Chaos, where the colors were a bit wonky.)

Comment: Unfortunately the first Gatherer search here is now broken as sometime in the past 8 years they re-templated cards so they no longer say "to your mana pool".

Answer (score 5):

**White** has very little ramp of its own; the effects it *does* have relating to mana are generally dependent on you controlling fewer lands than your opponent, and most of those put land in your hand, rather than on the field (which is not ramp). Examples: [Land Tax](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Land%20Tax), [Kor Cartographer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kor%20Cartographer), [Knight of the White Orchid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Knight%20of%20the%20White%20Orchid), [Oath of Lieges](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Oath%20of%20Lieges).

**Blue** also has very little. [Dreamscape Artist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dreamscape%20Artist) is a spellshaper that knows a color-shifted version of [Harrow](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Harrow), there's the infamous [High Tide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=High%20Tide), and most (all?) of the "free mana" cards from Urza block are blue, such as [Palinchron](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Palinchron). Don't forget twiddling effects that can hit lands, like [Turnabout](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Turnabout)!

**Black** has enough ramp to spawn an archetype -- Big Mana Black! Between cards like [Cabal Coffers](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cabal%20Coffers), [Nirkana Revenant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nirkana%20Revenant), [Crypt Ghast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Crypt%20Ghast), [Liliana of the Dark Realms](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liliana%20of%20the%20Dark%20Realms) (ultimate), [Skirge Familiar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skirge%20Familiar), and rituals along the lines of [Dark Ritual](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Ritual), a black deck can achieve absurd amounts of mana.

**Devotion** If your deck is a devotion deck [Nykthos, Shrine to Nyx](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nykthos%2C%20Shrine%20to%20Nyx) is a powerful ramp card.

While older black cards included many rituals, modern rituals tend to be **Red**. See: [Battle Hymn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Battle%20Hymn), [Brightstone Ritual](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brightstone%20Ritual), [Desperate Ritual](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Desperate%20Ritual), [Infernal Plunge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Infernal%20Plunge), [Koth of the Hammer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Koth%20of%20the%20Hammer) (first two abilities), [Mana Geyser](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mana%20Geyser), [Pyretic Ritual](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pyretic%20Ritual), [Seething Song](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Seething%20Song), etc.

Comment: Note that the black ramp tends to be more about getting you from a decent amount of mana to tons of mana. The permanent spells you listed cost 4 and up, and Cabal Coffers needs four swamps to come out in your favor. The things that can get you going earlier are one-offs, rituals and some sacrifice for mana type stuff.

Comment: @Jefromi, True. Of course, if one of the lands in play is Urborg, Tomb of Yawgmoth, then Coffers counts itself, too =)

Comment: Don't forget Witch Engine :P

Comment: For White and Blue, you could put that they have a lot to reduce the cost of spells instead of generating more mana.

Answer (score 1):

Terrain Generator is a land that not only can add colorless mana but if you have extra land at the end of your opponents turn it allows you to put a basic into play

Answer (score 0):

Why does nobody list [Sisters of the Flame](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSisters%20of%20the%20Flame%5d) (1RR). Taps for a red mana. A 4th Edition & The Dark card.

Comment: You just did ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few, but they aren't very common, and most aren't repeatable effects. I won't list what everyone has already said again, but there are a few I haven't seen mentioned that probably should be:

- [Simian Spirit Guide](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSimian%20Spirit%20Guide%5d) - exile from the hand for [image: {R}]
- [Skirk Prospector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSkirk%20Prospector%5d) - sacrifice goblins for [image: {R}]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get more than one lands into play in a single turn is to recur lands (especially fetchlands) from your graveyard. White in particular uses this strategy since it has some decent cards capable of bringing back permanents and lacks some other more direct ways to ramp.

Cards like [Second Sunrise](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSecond%20Sunrise%5d), [Brought Back](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrought%20Back%5d), and [Faith's Reward](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFaith%27s%5d%2b%5bReward%5d) can interact with fetchlands (e.g. [Arid Mesa](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArid%20Mesa%5d)) that were sacrificed to put them back onto the battlefield for a second use. Or more direct permanent recursion like [Sun Titan](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSun%20Titan%5d) can also return lands to the battlefield and act as mana ramp.

Answer (score 0):

There'd [Braid of Fire](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBraid%20of%20Fire%5d), but that's only upkeep.

You can also take control of your opponents' lands such as with [Annex](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnnex%5d), [Agent of Treachery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAgent%20of%20Treachery%5d) or [Conquer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConquer%5d). [Chandra, Novice Pyromancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Novice%20Pyromancer%5d) can give you RR for a loyalty counter. Combine it with [Chandra's Regulator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%27s%5d%2b%5bRegulator%5d) and [Chandra, Acolyte of Flame](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChandra%2c%20Acolyte%20of%20Flame%5d) and you can get RRR each turn.

There's also cards that take you extra turns, which is mana acceleration in some sense.

Answer (score 0):

Blue has a minor theme styled as individuals creating mana to cast (in-world) spells. This tends to manifest in a way that interacts with the card's set's flavor.

Some examples:

- [Apprentice Wizard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bApprentice%20Wizard%5d)
- [Grand Architect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrand%20Architect%5d)
- [Deranged Assistant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeranged%20Assistant%5d)
- [Qarsi Deceiver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bQarsi%20Deceiver%5d)
- [Cultivator Drone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCultivator%20Drone%5d)
- [Vodalian Arcanist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVodalian%20Arcanist%5d)
- [Karfell Harbinger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarfell%20Harbinger%5d)